PROBLEMA AL QUERER REINICIALIZAR una ID a 0
Tengo 2 clases, una Producto y otra orden, en mi main eh creado un arraylist de tipo orden
para ingresar varias ordenes, pero quisiera que cada vez que se vaya a mostrar una orden con el metodo de mostrarOrden la idProducto comienze desde 0 de nuevo. Lo que eh intentado es poner Producto.idProductoProgre = 0 en el constructor de orden pero igual sigue sin reiniciarse.
CLASE PRODUCTO
package Ejercicio1Parcialpe;
public class Producto {
    protected static int idProductoProgre=0;
    private int idProducto=0;
    private String nombre;
    private double precioProducto;

    public Producto() {
        idProductoProgre++;
        idProducto=idProductoProgre;
    }

    public Producto(String nombre, double precioProducto) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precioProducto = precioProducto;
        idProductoProgre++;
        idProducto=idProductoProgre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Producto{" +"Id del producto="+idProducto + "nombre=" + nombre + ", precioProducto=" + precioProducto + '}';
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecioProducto() {
        return precioProducto;
    }

    public void setPrecioProducto(double precioProducto) {
        this.precioProducto = precioProducto;
    }

    public int getIdProducto() {
        return idProducto;
    }
    
    
}

CLASE ORDEN
package Ejercicio1Parcialpe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Orden{ 
    private static int idOrdenProgre=0;
    private int idOrden = 0;
    private ArrayList<Producto> producto = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public Orden() {
        idOrdenProgre++;
        idOrden=idOrdenProgre;
    }
    
    public void agregarProducto(Producto produc){
        producto.add(produc);
    }
    public double calcularTotal(){
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < producto.size(); i++) {
            total+=producto.get(i).getPrecioProducto();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void mostrarOrden(){
        System.out.println("-------Numero de orden["+idOrden+"]--------");
        for (int i = 0; i < producto.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Id del producto: "+producto.get(i).getIdProducto());
            System.out.println("Nombre del producto: "+producto.get(i).getNombre());
            System.out.println("Precio del producto: "+producto.get(i).getPrecioProducto());
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("Total a pagar: "+calcularTotal());
        
    }
    
}

MAIN
package Ejercicio1Parcialpe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ejerc1Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Orden> ordenes = new ArrayList<Orden>();
        ordenes.add(new Orden());
        ordenes.add(new Orden());

        ordenes.get(0).agregarProducto(new Producto("Cel", 200));
        ordenes.get(0).agregarProducto(new Producto("Olla", 100));
        ordenes.get(0).agregarProducto(new Producto("Sarten", 50));
        
        ordenes.get(0).mostrarOrden();
        System.out.println("");
        
        ordenes.get(1).agregarProducto(new Producto("Zapatilla", 300));
        ordenes.get(1).agregarProducto(new Producto("Set de platos", 150));
        ordenes.get(1).agregarProducto(new Producto("Mousepad", 100));
        
        ordenes.get(1).mostrarOrden();
    }
    
}


En la imagen en el numero de orden 2, en vez de que sea "Id del producto: 4 " sea "Id del producto: 1"

Yo creo que es un problema de que estás intentando usar una variable estática en la clase producto, cuando esa variable debería ser de la clase orden (y no ser estática!). Es la orden quien sabe qué id le tiene que poner al producto, es la orden quien debe gestionarla. En el método agregarProducto deberías setearle la id al producto que le pasas antes de guardarlo, simplemente. De esa manera cada orden gestionará su propio valor incremental y no tendrás uno común para muchas órdenes diferentes. Porque qué pasa si creas dos órdenes y luego le agregas productos alternándolos??

hola Renzo, bienvenido, yo empezaría por replantear el problema y los nombres de las variables, "id" debe ser un identificador de producto, (n°  de serie, nombre..), luego tendrías un "itemCount" que llevaría la cantidad de productos de cada orden (que reinicias cada vez que terminas la orden), por último, si es que lo necesitas, un "productCount" que representaría la cantidad de productos creados (que sería una variable estática), creo que con eso puedes sacarlo adelante sin ayuda.
